# New content not showing on site unless user clears cache

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching

**My problem**

Ive got this little annoying problem, which really affects my regular users on my website.

If I add new content to a page on my site, only the old cached version of my site shows up, **new text/images/links/divs wont show up unless the user clears his or her cache.**

*Is this a normal thing?*

**Solutions?**

How can I work around it so that new content can be seen without user having to clear their cache to view new content?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following headers:

- `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`
- `Pragma: no-cache`
- `Expires: 0`

I don't know if it will help much in the case of a page that is already cached for a user (before these headers were added).

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/1730078) for more details.